# sql query for checking status of every ticket as time duration

Tags: sql-server

I have a table ticket which have ticketid,owner,ownerdate columns. I want to calculate the time duration of every ticket by which it is processed. Table is as...

```
ticketid  owner     owndate
1001     LEWIS    2004-06-18 14:15:11
1001     WILSON   2004-06-18 14:16:54
1001     WILSON   2004-06-18 14:21:12
1001     (null)   2004-09-01 09:56:11
1001     CALDONE  2005-02-02 08:38:28
1001     SINCLA   2005-02-02 08:54:02
1002    (null)    2005-02-02 08:40:06
1002     REID     2015-01-16 15:18:05
1002     SMALL    2015-01-16 15:19:53
1002    WILSON    2004-06-18 14:33:47
1002    (null)    2004-08-31 15:12:46
1002    (null)    2004-09-24 10:03:09
1003    RAMSDA    2004-09-24 10:04:24
1003    MOTIKA    2004-08-31 14:51:45
1003    (null)    2004-08-31 15:05:50
1003    MURTHY    2004-09-02 14:50:28
1004    (null)    2004-08-31 15:28:37
1004    (null)    2004-09-24 09:24:21
1005    MOTIKA    2004-08-31 14:47:19
1005    MOTIKA    2004-08-31 17:20:33
```

I want the output as-------

```
ticketid    owner1      owner2      owner3   
1001         43            240        134
```

The owner1 value is time duration of for lewis (2004-06-18 14:16:54) - (2004-06-18 14:15:11)

The owner1 value is time duration of for wilson (2004-09-01 09:56:11) - (2004-06-18 14:16:54)

Comment: What have you tried, where is your code to show you have actually try to do something yourselve. SO is not a helpdesk

Comment: I recently used this query to calculate the time difference of the ticketid as...select t1.ticketID,  
 duration=  datediff(s, max(t2.owndate), t1.owndate)
from tkownerhistory t1 join tkownerhistory t2 on t1.ticketid = t2.ticketid 
       and t2.owndate < t1.owndate
group by t1.ticketid,t1.owndate order by ticketid,t1.owndate
  but want the result as shown below                                             ticketid    owner1             owner2      owner3   
1001         43sec            240sec        134sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have made the query with perfect output.

```
select ticketid,
owner1=CONVERT(varchar(10),owner2-owner1,108),
owner2=CONVERT(varchar(10),owner3-owner2,108),
owner3=CONVERT(varchar(10),owner4-owner3,108),
owner4=CONVERT(varchar(10),owner4,108)from
(
select ticketid,owndate,'owner'+cast(ROW_NUMBER() over 
(partition by ticketid order by owndate) as varchar(10)) as sno from tkownerhistory                
) tbl
pivot
(
max(owndate)
for sno in(owner1,owner2,owner3,owner4)
)pvt'
```